# SQLite unique column based on foreign key

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
create table a(
    _id integer primary key,
   name integer,
   message integer unique
);
```

Message column must be unique only when name columns are the same. How can I achieve that?

Example:

```
insert into a(name, message) values (1, 5)
```

This must throw error:

```
insert into a(name, message) values (1, 5)
```

This must work:

```
insert into a(name, message) values (2, 5)
insert into a(name, message) values (1, 6)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

you can set this column to unique by click to icon unique in tables list

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD CONSTRAINT constr_ID UNIQUE (user_id, game_id, date, time)
```

Comment: At least make it relevant to the fields provided in the question so that it is clear to the OP how the syntax works.

Comment: This is not even valid SQLite syntax.